# Two Separate Scrollable Fragments on the Same View - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a basic UI for a simple Temperature Conversion app (new to android developing), and I can't figure out how to create a SINGLE page with two SEPARATE scrollable view pagers, one occupying the top half and the other occupying the bottom one.

I am using Eclipse. Feel free to ask for any other information required for your answer.

This is a rough drawing of what the layout should look like.

[image]

Comment: Well I'm new to Android apps but I have tried to create two view pagers on the same view; no luck there. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: When asking a question, I'd recommend posting the code (both relevant Java and layout XML) you tried and describing exactly how it didn't work (including any stack traces, error messages, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create a basic UI for a simple Temperature Conversion app

I do not know why a temperature conversion app would need one `ViewPager`, let alone two in the same activity at the same time.

> I can't figure out how to create a SINGLE page with two SEPARATE scrollable view pagers, one occupying the top half and the other occupying the bottom one

In terms of the `ViewPager`s themselves, use a `LinearLayout` or something to vertically stack them.

Your bigger headache will come with the `PagerAdapter` implementations. At least one of these will have to be something other than `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Those implementations assume that they are the only such adapter for your activity, and I would expect that having two will cause collisions.

Comment: Two view pagers so you can scroll between temperature units (C, F, K, etc) and the value on the other view pager changes accordingly.

Comment: @SamJaved: IMHO, that's not a suitable use case for `ViewPager`. But, you are welcome to do whatever you want.

Comment: What do you suggest to be used in this case?

Comment: @SamJaved: Unless they invented a new one since I went to college, there are only three significant units for temperature: Celsius, Fahrenheit, and Kelvin. Each is a short word, even shorter if you stick with the single-letter abbreviations. The user should not need a gesture to be able to see the various options. Moreover, some combinations are silly (converting Kelvin to Kelvin). If you're open to third-party code, this seems like a great place for a segmented radio button (e.g., https://github.com/vinc3m1/android-segmentedradiobutton).

Comment: Well there's about 8 or 9 more units. And I was doing the scrollable tabs because it looks simple and easy to use for people who don't like to move their hands a lot; one single swipe. Although, I just might switch to having all the units on a single screen. Thank you, though.